# sed + search word with strings and replaced all word

Tags: linux, sed

I want to create with sed the following:

for example each word in the file that have the "ssss..."
Should be replaced (all word) with target string as gggg

```
 echo "duwdbnhb ssssssmnfkejfnei" | sed s'/ssssss*/gggg/g'

 duwdbnhb ggggmnfkejfnei
```

should be:

```
 duwdbnhb gggg
```

remark - string could be with couple of "s" strings ( for example ss or sss or ssssss )

example:

```
 echo "duwdbnhb sssmnfkejfnei" | sed s'/s*/gggg/g'

 duwdbnhb gggg



 echo "duwdbnhb sssmnfdej3434bjhhji" | sed s'/s*/gggg/g'

 duwdbnhb gggg
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "blabla sssssololo" |sed 's/s*.[^ ]*/gggg/g'
blabla gggg`

However if your 'sssss' will occur not only at begin of a word, you may use
`echo "blabla onetwosssssololo" |sed 's/[^ ]*s*.[^ ]*/gggg/g'
blabla gggg`